# How to deploy an Outlook macro?

Tags: vba, outlook

I made an Outlook macro. How can I deploy it to use it on some other machine?

Do I follow the same steps I followed on my machine Tools-> Macros-> create new or is there another way to deploy as we do with the vb or C# projects?

Comment: I mean on a machine which doesn't have VB or Visual Studio installed.

Comment: You don't need visual studio installed on the target machine - just outlook, but I don't know if there is a way to deploy macros like that.

Comment: I have a windows server 2008 machine with outlook 32 bit installed.But when i navigate to Tools->macros it shows everything highlighted i can't select or create any macros.Do you know why is that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to follow the same steps and re-record the entire macro from scratch. You can save the module containing the macro and import it in Outlook on the other machine.

In Outlook's VBA editor, right-click your module > Export File...

Then on the other machine, in Outlook's VBA editor, right-click your project > Import File...

**EDIT** You say that your Outlook doesn't have VB Editor. Quoting from Outlook help:

> you may be running a Microsoft Office
> program with the Visual Basic for
> Applications (VBA) shared feature disabled.

I don't know what version of Outlook you have, but for 2003:

> To re-enable VBA, follow these steps:
>
> 1.Run the Office Setup program again.  How? Quit all programs.Double-click
> the Add/Remove Programs icon in the
> Microsoft Windows Control Panel.Do one
> of the following: If you installed
> your Office program as part of
> Microsoft Office, click Microsoft
> Office in the Currently installed
> programs box, and then click the
> Change button.If you installed your
> Office program individually, click the
> name of your program in the Currently
> installed programs box, and then click
> the Change button.
>
> 2.On the Features to install screen in the Setup program, click the plus sign
> (+) next to Office Shared Features.
>
> 3.Select Visual Basic for Applications, click the arrow next to
> your selection, and then click Run
> from My Computer.

Comment: But the outlook which i have doesn't have Visual Basic Editor.Any help??

Answer (score 1):

Usually outlook macros are only made for personnal use. Distributing them can be hard as it needs too much actions made by the user (add "devoloper" in ribbon, open visual basic editor, import files, enable references, enable security...).

**Microsoft** wrote:

> *If you are developing a solution that you intend to distribute to more than a few people, you should convert your VBA code into an Outlook COM or VSTO add-in or an Office add-in for Outlook.*

(source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/290779/managing-and-distributing-outlook-visual-basic-for-vba).

Knowing that, i recommend you to write a VSTO add-in and deploy it using ClickOnce.

You can start by these links:

**VSTO**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/getting-started-programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019

**ClickOnce deployment**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2019